# The external column "y.col1" (598) needs to be removed from the external columns

Tags: ssis

I am using below query in sql command from variable to fetch data from two different tables.

```
SELECT x.*, y.col1, y.col2
FROM table1 AS x 
INNER JOIN table2 AS y ON y.AccID = x.accID
```

As per my business logic I need to use the query as **sql command from variable**.
When I run the package after setting **DelayValidation** to **True**, I get the below errors:

```
"[OLE source **table1**]] Warning: The external columns for component 
"OLE source" (1) are out of synchronization with the data source columns.
The external column "**col2**" (601) needs to be removed from the external columns.
The external column "**Col1**" (598) needs to be removed from the external columns."..

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "component "OLE source **table1** " (1)" failed validation
and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
```

Answer (score 2):

The change in your SQL affected the settings of your OLE Source component. You need to revisit the column assignments for your SQL's output. Also, you will have to check on your destination SSIS component to see if there are any changes that will impact it too. Each and every time you change your SQL, make it a habit to double check the sql-column-to-component-column assignments.

`Warning: The external columns for component 
"OLE source" (1) are out of synchronization with the data source columns.` means that a change in your component had been detected. Turning **DelayValidation** to TRUE simply means that no component validations will take place in design time.

`The external column "**col2**" (601) needs to be removed from the external columns.
The external column "**Col1**" (598) needs to be removed from the external columns."..` will help point you in the direction of where your assignments may have gone wrong. It seems that it might be possible that you reduced your columns or added them sometime before the package was executed. This is where strictness of the component validations come into place -- there's also a chance that you only changed the case of your SQL command (in this case maybe the column name) and that alone can trigger `"VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"`.

Again, recheck your component's column assignments, and if you change any part in your source component's column settings, it will impact the destination (and if any, other data transformations in between) as well.

Comment: You mention checking things, but how do I make the error go away?  There doesn't seem to be a button every time that helps me resolve the problem.