# SSDT - columns out of synchronization - blocks update to table

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis, synchronization, package

Process - first off, i would like to just use a program to enter data into the SQL table but due to certain ... issues ... this is not an option.

Excel sheet has set column headers - they do not change - excel data for columns does change. new records are added and other are removed daily. i have a project in SSDT 2015:

1. clear temp table - delete from tbldatemp
2. data flow task
   a. source: excel sheet - access mode: table or view
   b. Data conversion 0-0 - some conversions necessary for sql to accept data
   c. destination - tbldatemp
3. update main tblda - insert into where not exists a.[blah] = b.[blah] etc etc etc

so every day the data in excel changes. i have a vb.net program that executes the update package with the click of a button - and every day it doesn't work. so i open up the project in SSDT and see a nice yellow ! triangle on my data flow task stating that columns are out of synchronization. when i open up the data flow task, the ! is now on the excel source stating columns are out of synchronization.

i have looked for DAYS trying to figure out how to fix this or get around it and cannot figure it out. please help!!!!  Thank you

Comment: Try setting DelayValidation=true on your Excel source in SSIS.  Also in the data flow component's Properties, ValidateExternalMetadata to False.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24313857/1507566

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql? Are you pushing data into it using SSIS?

Comment: sorry - if the tag is incorrect - i am using SSDT import / export as part of a dtsx project to perform an update. stackoverflow suggested i use multiple tags involving sql to get better results.

Comment: thank you alleman - i will be trying this on monday morning - will post if it works...i hope so!!