# SSIS Parameterize Mappings

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got a parent package that I'm hoping to use to call several hundred versions of the same child package, in order to perform an incremental load from an ODBC data source to SQL Server.  Here's a screenshot of the parent package:

[Parent Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPaHr.png)

The GetTableList task grabs the information for all the ODBC tables I want to incrementally load from Excel.

[TableInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzmSe.png)

It stores this in variables and uses the "Execute Package Task" to pass them to the child package, telling it which table to load.  Here are the parameter bindings:

[Parameter Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQiHD.png)

I'm using a single child package, choosing which table to load based on the "Table" parameter passed (shown above) from the parent package. The child package control flow is shown below.  It contains (among other things) two data flow tasks which:

- Download the full set of primary key fields from the source into a staging table
- Download any records that have changed since the last load into the final table

Child Package Control Flow:

[image]

It's mostly working.  I've been able to parameterize the Execute SQL Tasks, the Data Source Queries in the data flows, the connection managers, and the destination tables, all using parameters passed from the parent package.

However, the data flows are giving me an error. It appears that SSIS won't automatically "map" the source columns to the destination, as shown below:

[Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HTZB.png)

The column names and data types match. Normally I would just go into the mappings page and connect them directly, but because I'm trying to use the same child package to load all the tables, I can't do this - it has to be automatic. 
How do I create the mappings?

I tried what's shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313478/ssis-error-external-column-for-source-out-of-sync-with-data-source-columns-how) including marking "validate external metadata as false." The mapping errors now are all shown on the OLEDB destination:

```
Error: 0xC0202005 at GetKeys, dw_keys [2]: Column "codeiden" cannot be found at the datasource.

Error: 0xC0202025 at GetKeys, dw_keys [2]: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.

Error: 0xC004701A at GetKeys, SSIS.Pipeline: dw_keys failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
```

Comment: Unclear.  What does this sentence mean?   "I can't figure out how to make them map to each-other using parameters."

Comment: Thanks Tab.  I mean I can't figure out how to generate and repair the mappings.  When I go into the data flow and click on the destination, I can right-click "Map items by matching names".  And when there are unmapped columns, I can double-click on the connection and select "delete unmapped columns." I'd like to do both of these things automatically.

Comment: What mappings are you talking about?  Where is this "Map items by matching names"?   Are you using the import wizard or something besides just SSIS?   I think your question would benefit from some screenshots.   I still have no idea where you are.

Comment: Sorry - I've added some screenshots.  I'm not using the import wizard, just Source and Destination tasks in the Data Flow.  In the destination task you "map" the source columns to the destination columns.  It appears that I can't make this happen automatically, which prevents me from using the same child package to load all the tables.  I don't yet have enough points to embed the screenshots, so they have to be links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually upon further research I found that it is possible to do this using the CozyRoc Data Flow Plus product as explained in [this blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/introducing-etl-assistant-dynamic-templated-approach-ssis-whitley/).

Basically it allows you to create a data flow with dynamic column mapping. You can't use an ODBC data source, but you can use an ADO.NET data source with the ODBC driver, and you can also dynamically map the Data Conversion task to account for how the ADO.NET source forces you into Unicode columns.

It appears that I don't even need a Parent package, but just a ForEach loop that I can pass a RecordSet containing the table information to for all the tables I want to load.

The key is marking everything as "DelayValidation" and all data flow tasks as "ValidateExternalMetadata" to false when using the CozyRoc product.

Just using trial version for now, and will have to determine if the cost is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand you now, and the answer is no.   Destination column mappings cannot be dynamically assigned at run time, regardless of whether a package is a child, parent or stand-alone.

Destination column mappings must be assigned at package creation time and cannot change during run time.

Comment: Ok.  So then it appears that it's not possible to use a single child package to make multiple table data transfers.  I guess I need to learn Biml :)

Comment: Only if all of the tables have the exact same columns (names and datatypes).